# How to set a List of strings as a key's value in yaml file using terraform's helm_release resource

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm, argocd, onelogin

The code is used to patch the argocd config map to add SSO authentication.

```
resource "helm_release" "argocd" {
  name             = "argocd"
  create_namespace = "true"
  chart            = "argo-cd"
  namespace        = "argocd"
  version          = "5.16.9"
  repository       = "https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm"

  set {
    name = "configs.cm.url"
    value = "https://cypherphage.com"
  }

  set {
    name = "server.config.oidc\\.config"
    value = yamlencode({
        "name" = "Onelogin"
        "issuer" = "https://example.onelogin"
        "clientID" = "82348237984732927493928"
        "clientSecret" = "hjsadjdhg38q7eaw"
        "requestedScopes" = "['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'groups']"
    })
  }
}
```

The argocd-cm config map yaml file should look like this (focus on the requestedScopes key at the end) ->

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: argocd-cm
  namespace: argocd
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: argocd
data:
  url: https://<argocd.myproject.com>
  oidc.config: |
    name: OneLogin
    issuer: https://<subdomain>.onelogin.com/oidc/2
    clientID: aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    clientSecret: abcdef123456

    # Optional set of OIDC scopes to request. If omitted, defaults to: ["openid", "profile", "email", "groups"]
    requestedScopes: ["openid", "profile", "email", "groups"]
```

But I can't seem to create the yaml file where the value of key "requestedScopes" is in a single line like

```
requestedScopes: ["openid", "profile", "email", "groups"]
```

The best I could achieve was:

```
requestedScopes: 
  - openid 
  - profile
  - email
```

What I have tried:

```
"requestedScopes" = "['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'groups']"
"requestedScopes" = "[\"openid\", \"profile\", \"email\", \"groups\"]"
```

Errors that I get:

```
helm_release.argocd: Modifying... [id=argocd]
╷
│ Error: failed parsing key "server.config.oidc\\.config" with value "clientID": "82348237984732927493928"
│ "clientSecret": "hjsadjdhg38q7eaw"
│ "issuer": "https://example.onelogin"
│ "name": "Onelogin"
│ "requestedScopes": "['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'groups']"
│ , key " 'profile'" has no value (cannot end with ,)
│ 
│   with helm_release.argocd,
│   on main.tf line 38, in resource "helm_release" "argocd":
│   38: resource "helm_release" "argocd" {
```

```
╷
│ Error: failed parsing key "server.config.oidc\\.config" with value "clientID": "82348237984732927493928"
│ "clientSecret": "hjsadjdhg38q7eaw"
│ "issuer": "https://example.onelogin"
│ "name": "Onelogin"
│ "requestedScopes": "[\"openid\", \"profile\", \"email\", \"groups\"]"
│ , key " \"profile\"" has no value (cannot end with ,)
│ 
│   with helm_release.argocd,
│   on main.tf line 26, in resource "helm_release" "argocd":
│   26: resource "helm_release" "argocd" {
```

Comment: `"requestedScopes" = ["openid", "profile", "email", "groups"]`

what exactly you mean by `The best I could achieve was:` because that section and `requestedScopes: ["openid", "profile", "email"]` are equal.  

They are two types of array definition syntax in yaml , ref https://www.w3schools.io/file/yaml-arrays/

Also, I am not sure if you are referring to the correct values at `server.config.oidc\\.config`  check argocd helm chart. Maybe you mean `configs.cm.oidc\\.config` ref values:  https://github.com/argoproj/argo-helm/blob/argo-cd-5.16.9/charts/argo-cd/values.yaml#L152C7-L152C19

Comment: Got it, my bad. But then how can I set these values https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/user-management/onelogin/#configure-permissions-for-onelogin-authd-users

Answer (score 0):

Bit late but this is how i went about it, just provide it all as a string

```
 set_sensitive {
    name  = "server.config.oidc\\.config"
    type  = "string"
    value = <<-YAML
      name: xx
      issuer: ${var.sso_oidc_issuer_url}
      clientID: ${var.sso_oidc_client_id}
      clientSecret: ${var.sso_oidc_client_secret}
      requestedScopes:
        - openid
        - profile
        - email
        - xx
    YAML
  }
```